# How to make a field required if the request is POST but if the request is PUT the field not required? (django model)

Tags: django, reactjs, model, field

I created a model of 7 fields where all fields `blank=True, null=True` but one of them is required. The problem is I want to make it required only the the `request` is a `POST` otherwise its not required for example: in case if a `PUT` method users don't need to mention at all.

Answer (score 0):

what about making a checker in views.py function itself?
in views.py

```
def ...(request):
   if request.method == 'PUT':
       if not <field you want>:
           <will run if the field was empty>
       else:
           <will run if there was a value>
   elif request.method == 'POST':
       <will run if the method is POST>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not base your firlds requirements on your request type, but rather on your props.

I assume that if you're editing a model, you have pre-filled fields, which means you have access to your model data within your component.

SO, instead of focusing on your request type, do something like this:

```js
import React from 'react'

const myComponent = ({ myData = {}}) => {
  return (
    <input type='text' required={ myData && myData.whatever } />
  )  
}

export default myComponent
```

By using this syntax, your field will only be required if you're passing an existing model.

Comment: Yes I already did ```setState(pre=>{...pre,newdata})``` but I'm trying to find a more elegant way

Comment: I assume that you are pretty new to React, so it's alright if you struggle a bit at first ! For now, can you edit your question so that you include some pieces of code ? Especially the component that includes the form.